# How to convert date time to mysql date format in php

Tags: php, mysql, date

How to convert below date format into mysql date format for fetch data,

```
01:14:30 PM Wed 6th September 2017
```

My tried code is below,

```
$t= "01:14:30 PM Wed 6th September 2017";
echo date("Y/m/d H:i:s",strtotime($t));
```

but not get exact result, I get reult `2017/09/06 00:00:00` ,
I need to get exact result like `2017-09-06 13:14:30`
How to get my exact result ,Any help appreciated

Comment: you can use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php) for such special formats to be converted to a date.

Comment: You also aren't using the correct delimiters in your specified date format... use hyphens/dashes not slashes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just put the time at the end.

```
$t= "Wed 6th September 2017 01:14:30 PM ";
```

Comment: getting same result like 2017-09-06 00:00:00

Comment: @Thiyagu That was before setTime

Comment: @Thiyagu  if you can reorder you string, just put the time at the end of the string. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

> Working Demo: https://eval.in/859020

```
  <?php

//$Date = new DateTime("01:14:30 PM Wed 6th September 2017");
//$New_Date = date(Y-m-d h:i:s,strtotime(01:14:30 PM Wed 6th September 2017)); 
//echo $New_Date;

$Current_Date = "01:14:30 PM Wed 6th September 2017";

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat(' h:i:s A D dS M Y',$Current_Date);
echo $new_date_format = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

?>
```

**Output:** `2017-09-10 03:41:38`

Comment: you overwrite `$Date`. gives current date/time now...

Comment: @Jeff ,, I know that but its fine

Comment: yes, this overwrite the $date to current details

Answer (score -1):

You are using `/` instead of `-` date string format.

For getting timestamp i.e. date with time use `Y-m-d H:i:s` string format:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($t));
```

For getting only date, use `Y-m-d` format:

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($t));
```